# Azure and SQL Server: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database

Using Azure with SQL Server. In 30% of the cases where the SimpleRoleProvider is implicitly called we get an error: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server. The error occurs frequently but is not reproducible. It looks like a timeout..

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
   ...
}
```

The stack trace looks like:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
```

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296071
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +889
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +558
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +67
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +88
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +239
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +762
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +54
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9461104

We don't have this problem on our own server. Is this a configuration issue? We are using the free trail version of Azure yet.

--- ADDITION ---

The bad thing is that the MVC-framework "handles" the request, in the example given (Role 
Management). The use of the framework is to add an abstraction layer to handle "domain request" conveniently. So what to do in this case?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Strange, but we have the feeling that the error occurs more frequently using IExplorer (versus Chrome).

Comment: I don't think this is browser related issue. From where are you connecting to the DB? Is your web-server on premise?

Comment: The database is an Azure database. Yes, you're right, it can't be a browser issue. Still, statistically, Chrome works better(!?!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by Azure and SQL Server you mean the [SAAS Azure SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/) (the names change faster than I can keep track), not the IAAS [SQL Server on Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj823132.aspx). First thing ou need to determine wether your application is being throttled, see [Connection Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#cc) and give this article a good, thorrough read: [Causes of Connection Termination](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx#Reasons). If your application is being throttled then you need to revisit your design and address the specific reason why you're being throttled.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We deployed our local database to Sql Azure, guess that makes it a SQL Server on Windows Azure. Most of the sessions are throttled due to a timeout. The bad thing is that the MVC-framework "handles" the request in the example given. The use of the framework is to add an abstraction layer to handle "domain request" conveniently. So what to do in this case?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'throttled due to timeout'. Throttled means a very specific state of your subscription, is not just another name for 'error'. Please **read the articles linked carefully** and follow the advice there.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected on SQL Azure. It should happen on about 0.5% of the time, not 30%.

[Here's a previous question that addressed this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303780/sql-azure-database-retry-logic)

> Connection failures in SQL Azure are common. This is because your
>   application will create a connection pool but while your side thinks
>   these connections are over, Azure could terminate them at their end
>   and you will never know about it.

You should implement a retry logic on your code in case one of these timeouts occur. Microsoft already has a library for this: the [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)