# Web Server - The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, semaphore

I am getting the following error when trying to run a web application on Windows Server 2008 R2. Getting this error when the application is trying to connect to the database. However, I am able to run the application without any issues on another web server(Windows Server 2008 R2).

I see that there were a lot of posts on this error, but I couldn't get a solution out of it for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Error:**

**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)**

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

**Source Error**:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

[SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)]

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +89
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +207
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error) +502
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +153
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer() +39
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte() +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +108
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +36
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +367
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +492
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +29
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +437
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +449
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +116
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +478
   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters) +123
   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText) +11
   Providence.Internet.MyAccount.Utilities.ServiceAreaUtilities.GetServiceAreasFromDataBase() +168
   Providence.Internet.MyAccount.Utilities.ServiceAreaUtilities.GetServiceAreas() +100
   LabTestCatalog.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +45

[HttpException (0x80004005): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +407
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +130
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +296
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetPipelineApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +54
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +237

[HttpException (0x80004005): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +639
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +78
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +334
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999439/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired

Comment: Does your connection string contain `Connection Timeout=XX;` ?  If not try adding that, and if it does, try increasing the value of XX to say 60

Comment: Does that error always happen? Under what circumstances does it happen? How stable is the network?

Comment: What does the SQL Server error log show at the time this error happened?

Comment: Kept timeout as 100 in connection string and did not work. The strange part is - the application is running successfully in another web server of the same configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The semaphore timeout period has expired" SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207116/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired-sql-azure)

Answer (score -1):

This is a Windows error message usually given when there are problems with the network or network adapter. The following Microsoft KB article has more information:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325487